# Integer to guid primary key database migration

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, self-referencing-table

I'm trying to migrate from int based primary keys to guid based system, and I'm having trouble with migrating self referenced table

```
Entity
---------
ID
ParentID
AnotherParentID
```

When querying the table I'm creating new guid `ID` for each row, but how can I set that same guid value for rows that have  that `ID` as foreign key on `ParentID` or `AnotherParentID` fields?

```
SELECT 
    newid() as ID,
    (SELECT e.ID ...?) as ParentID,
    (SELECT e.ID ...?) as AnotherParentID,
FROM Entity e
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this in one pass, you'll have to retain the old and new keys and update accordingly.

Comment: Like store new and old key in temp table, and then just query new key from that table where OldID = RequestedID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MRsa answer gives multiple rows because of joining on `ParentID` or `AnotherParentID` (since multiple rows can have same ParentID/AnotherParentID).

This is my current implementation that works, I'm not sure if there is any better way to handle this

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    Id uniqueidentifier null,
    OldId integer null
)

INSERT INTO #tmp (Id, OldId)
SELECT NEWID(), Id FROM OldTable

INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT
    (SELECT Id FROM #tmp WHERE OldId = i.Id) as ID,
    (SELECT Id FROM #tmp WHERE OldId = i.ParentId) as ParentID,
    (SELECT Id FROM #tmp WHERE OldId = i.AnotherParentID) as AnotherParentID,
FROM OldTable i
```

Answer (score 1):

IF paretnIDs are Foreign keys:

```
Select NEWID(), ID, EP.ParentIDGUID, E.ParentID, EP2.AnotherParentID, EP2.AnotherParentIDGUID from dbo.Entity E  
        INNER JOIN 
        (Select MAX(NEWID()) as ParentIDGUID, ParentID FROM dbo.Entity GROUP BY ParentID) EP ON EP.ParentID = E.ParentID
        INNER JOIN 
        (Select MAX(NEWID()) as AnotherParentIDGUID, AnotherParentID FROM dbo.Entity GROUP BY AnotherParentID) EP2 ON EP2.AnotherParentID = E.AnotherParentID
```

or if they are foreign key on same table:

```
Select NEWID() as guidID, ID
INTO #tp 
 from dbo.Entity E


Select EP.ID, EP.guidID, E.ParentID, EP2.guidID, E.AnotherParentID, EP3.guidID from dbo.Entity E  
    INNER JOIN 
    #tp EP ON EP.ID = E.ID
    INNER JOIN 
    #tp EP2 ON EP2.ID = E.ParentID
    INNER JOIN 
    #tp EP3 ON EP3.ID = E.AnotherParentID


DROP TABLE #tp
```